# Python Itertools cycle output not working

Tags: python, cycle, python-itertools

I am trying to cycle through 2 python scripts within another script like this:

```
import itertools
import test
import test2

x = [test, test2]

cycle = itertools.cycle(x)

def x():
    global cycle
    return cycle.next()


for i in range(9):
    y = x()
    print y
```

When I run this it will print the first two correctly then the next 7 lines say

```
<module 'test' from 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\test.py'>
<module 'test2' from 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\test2.py'>
<module 'test' from 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\test.py'>
<module 'test2' from 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\test2.py'>
<module 'test' from 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\test.py'>
<module 'test2' from 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\test2.py'>
<module 'test' from 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\test.py'>
<module 'test2' from 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\test2.py'>
<module 'test' from 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\test.py'>
```

been searching but can't seem to find anything that might be causing this.

Comment: i don't understand your question. what other output would you have?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Well I was hoping the output would be the result of those files in a cycle.  Example:  Is test.py results in 2 and test2.py results in 4 the expected result of this script would be:

2
4
2
4
2
4
etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "the result of those files"?  test and test2 are run when you import them.

Comment: I mean test.py does "this" and test2.py does "that"  My questoin is ow to get the output of the script above to show "this" and "that' printed over again instead of seeing "<module 'test' from 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\test.py'>"

Comment: A request to "get the output of the script" is pretty much always a sign that you're doing something wrong. It's not _impossible_ to do—e.g., you could remove it from `sys.modules` if present, then redirect `sys.stdout` to a `StringIO`, then `import` it, then un-redirect `stdout`. But there are much easier, more robust, and more idiomatic ways to do it. Turn your top-level module code into a _function_, and have that function _return_ its results instead of printing them. Then you can just call that function to get its output.

Comment: Running `$python test.py` from the command line [actually runs *a function* in `test.py`](http://ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/module-name.html). This is **not** the same as `import`ing it into another module. Just like how you have to call `itertools.cycle`, you have to call `test.desired_function` to get the output you're looking for from `test.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is doing what you tell it to do:

when you do the `import test, import test2` at the beggining of your program,
those modules are run - and if they contain top-level print statements, it is at
this point those statements will generate output.

WHen you get to your `for i...` block, the program correctly associates your
`y` variable with the reference to the module. But printing the module object like you do,
don't cause the module to run again. Instead, the string representation of the modules is printed, and that is what you are seeing.

To achieve what I think you want,you have to encapsulate your output in a function inside your modules, say a "evaluator"  function which returns the desired value-/ and then, just change your line from

```
print y
```

to

```
print y.evaluator()
```